# Как поправить баг с закрытием окна, если кликаешь по календарю внутри него?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня в коде код, который закрывает окно при клике вне окна, но беда в том, что внутри этого окна есть календарь который нужен для работы, вот при клике на этот календарь окно закрывается и происходит беда!

**Как поправить?**

Баг:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код закрытия окна:

```
                    $(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу

                        if (!modal_content.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
                            && modal_content.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
                            $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().end();
                            mcloced(addclassmodal);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(modal_content).on('mouseup', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: скорее `stopPropagation`

Comment: так поставил чет не помогло... $(modal_content).on('mouseup', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // событие клика по веб-документу
        $modal.find('.modal-body').empty().end();
         mcloced(addclassmodal);
       
       });

Comment: @moonvvell чет не работает